# 'devMode' enabled on the frontend yet its set to false

Tags: devmode

I have recently migrated a website to the live server.

In the craft/config/general.php my 'devMode' is set to false.

In the backend of the website I am not seeing the yellow and black banner to say its in dev mode but on the frontend each meta title is starting with [devmode].

Regards,

Reece

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using SEOmatic; it has its own setting for the local environment you're using; check out this docs here: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/tree/develop#plugin-settings

Comment: Thank you for replying. The website doesnt have the SEOmatic plugin. It does have SEOmetrics but there are no options in here to edit the meta title.

I was wondering if there is cache that needs clearing. There is a plugin installed CacheMonster but the options are just "Enable Varnish purging?" and this is disabled.

As you can tell, I didn't build this website or have any experience with Craft CMS :)

Comment: Is this a Craft 3 or Craft 2 website? Sounds like from what you're saying that it's a Craft 2.x website. I'm fairly certain that SEOmatic is installed, because "SEOmetrics" comes from it...

Comment: Craft CMS 2.6.2961 - i just looks into SEOmetrics and it looks the same. I cant see the options in the backend that is shown in docs link you sent though.

Comment: Right, sorry, I assumed you use using the Craft 3 version. For the Craft 2 version, it just uses whatever `devMode` is set to. My guess is that somehow pages are cached running in `devMode`, then `devMode` was turned off, but the pages are still cached.

Answer (score 1):

andrew.welch was right in his comment. it looks as though clearing the cache missed a few pages and still showed 'devMode' - after a couple of days it was no longer appearing.